# using array_key_exists to pair up the amount total to id

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array that has several `amount`s (based on $$$ sales) attached to an `id` (where some of the `id`s are the same based on whom made a sale). My goal is to gather a total of `amount`s and attach each total to whichever `id` made the sale (truncating the identical `id`s from the array). I'm honestly not sure how to go about this as I'm still learning.

```
while ($row) {
    $operearnedArray[] = array(
      'amount' => $row['ChargeAmount'], 
      'id' => $row['OperatorID']);
}
//$operearnedArray returns the array with each "amount" attached to "id"
foreach ($operearnedArray as $key => $value) {
    if($value['id'] == '' || $value['id'] == null) {
        continue;
    }
    if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $operSums)) {
        $operSums[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
    } else {
        //I'm not sure where to go from here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo `while ($row) {`? You seem to have an infinite loop here.

Comment: No, it's not a typo, it's part of a query, I just took that part out. Appreciate your input though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, as for the comment, a simple

```
$operSums[$value['id']] = $value['amount'];
```

should do the trick. Of course it is adviseable to check for existent keys, but

```
foreach ($operearnedArray as $key => $value) {
    if($value['id'] == '' || $value['id'] == null) {
        continue;
    }
    $operSums[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
}
```

should work just as well, as you can see in [this demo](http://codepad.org/Mc6ar76k).

Comment: This worked like a charm, I don't know why I couldn't think of that lol. I know I'm tired, but I should have been able to figure this out! Thanks again kingkero!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
while ($row) {
    $operearnedArray[] = array(
      'amount' => $row['ChargeAmount'], 
      'id' => $row['OperatorID']);
}

$operSums = array();
foreach ( $operearnedArray as $sale ) {
    if ( ! $sale['id'] ) {
        continue;
    }
    $operSums[$sale['id']] += $sale['amount'];
}
// do something with the result, let's just look at it:
var_dump( $operSums );
```

It works: http://codepad.org/xGMNQauW